# Blitting FBO Color Attachments

Tags: go, opengl, gpu

I have 2 FBOs + MRT and they have identical attachments(4 color attachments each). using glBlitFrameBuffer works as expected for the depth buffer and for **one** color_attachment. However, when i blit multiple color attachments, things go bad. I have done a lot of research and tried a lot of different methods, none works. I am not using renderBufferStorage because my textures have different internal formats(RGBA and RGB16F). [This](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/951667/opengl/glblitframebuffer-between-multisample-fbo-source-and-simple-fbo-destination-to-resolve-multisamp/) sounds like a similar problem, except i am not using multisampling, only MRT.

OpenGL version 4.3

Why: I want to create a state of the terrain pre- lighting calculations so that i only need to render the terrain if there are changes(ie. camera movement) and then copy these color attachments to the next FBO. This is for deferred shading and the FBOs resembles the gBuffer a lot.

At first i expected that i should use glDrawBuffers which i am using in the initial setup, but there is no glReadBuffers and therefore i am assuming i have no way to link them. I might be wrong here, not an expert yet =)

Original code is written in Golang, should be easily transferable to C++ (will translate if requested).

UPDATE/SOLVED: For anyone stumbling onto this issue. When you are using glDrawBuffers() and using a call to glDrawBuffer() you are overwriting your glDrawBuffers() state. It needs to be reset to its orignal glDrawBuffers() state.

Update2: For those interested in a method like this i can confirm that it has incredible performance results, if you have a non-animated world and the camera doesn't move that often. For my purpose it is great (RTS), but for a FPS game like CS it would be a **very** bad approach.

Add the following after blitting (case specific):

```
var attachments = [4]uint32{gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3}
gl.DrawBuffers(4, &attachments[0])
```

FBO setup

```
gl.GenFramebuffers(1, &fbo.ID)
gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fbo.ID)

//setting up color attachments

gl.GenTextures(1, &fbo.Position)
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbo.Position)
gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB16F, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, nil)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
gl.FramebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbo.Position, 0)

//repeated 3 times for the additional color attachments

var attachments = [4]uint32{gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT3}
gl.DrawBuffers(4, &attachments[0])

gl.GenRenderbuffers(1, &fbo.DepthBuffer)
gl.BindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, fbo.DepthBuffer)
gl.RenderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, windowWidth, windowHeight)
gl.FramebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, fbo.DepthBuffer)

gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

And now to the blitting part.

```
gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIn.ID)
gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboOut.ID)

//works as expected
gl.BlitFramebuffer(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, gl.NEAREST)

//works as expected
gl.ReadBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
gl.DrawBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)
gl.BlitFramebuffer(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, gl.LINEAR)

//fails - no errors but produces some weird occurrences. 
gl.ReadBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1)
gl.DrawBuffer(gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1)
gl.BlitFramebuffer(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, gl.LINEAR)

gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to describe the problem more clearly.  All you state is `"when i blit multiple color attachments, things go bad"` and `"no errors but produces some weird occurrences"` which doesn't really help.  It might also be useful to see your fragment shader.  Does it definitely write to all of the colour attachments?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously worng in the given code snippets. The only _guess_ I can still make here is that maybe you screw up your drawbuffer state for the _next_ frame (if this is run in a loop, you might not immediately notice this). `glDrawBuffer()` basically undoes what you set with `glDrawBuffers()` in the FBO setup part. The draw buffer(s)  state is stored per FBO, and you modify it for the blitting, without restoring it (at least not in the code snippets posted so far).

Comment: @derhass you are absolutely correct! I just figured this out 5 minutes before you wrote :)
I had no idea the drawBuffer() call would overwrite the drawBuffers() init setup, it makes a lot of sense now. I just assumed it would return to its original FBO state drawBuffers() state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glDrawBuffer(x)` is conceptually equivalent to calling `GLenum bufs[1]={x}; glDrawBuffers(1, bufs)`. SInce the draw buffer state is part of the FBO state, your blitting code overwrites these states, and if these are not restored manually, the *rendering* afterwards will not work as intended. If you call this in a loop, this might lead to the wrong conclusion that the blitting is the issue, but in reality,the blitting is working correctly, just on wrong input data.

Comment: 1. I thought that setting the glDrawBuffers() during the initialization that it would stick with the framebuffer bind and then active when bound, just like VBOs in a VAO.
2. Also, i thought that glDrawBuffer() and glDrawBuffers() were two different functions and therefore it was not "unbinding" the FBOs draw state.

When you explain it like that, yes it makes sense that blit is doing what it supposed to and ofc. it shouldn't restore bindings after, that could potentially introduce a lot of unnecessary calls to OpenGL.